# Ajax call during page transition

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making an Ajax call and a page redirection from `<a>` tag.
Sample code :

```
<a onclick="return clickFn()" href="somelink"></a>
clickFn(){
  someAjaxCall()
  redirectPageByExtractingHrefFromTheElem()
  return false;
}
```

I know that once the ajax call is made and if the page redirects,then callback gets cancelled but the server will continue with the call.

But I am confused whether the ajax call will even be fired from browser till the page redirect call happens.
Because in my testing the above code does call the Ajax but the below code won't even fire ajax call, so I am not sure whether the first one is fool proof:

```
 <a onclick="return clickFn()" href="somelink"></a>
    clickFn(){
      someAjaxCall()
      return true;
    }
```

Can someone explain the flow of events?

Comment: Have you looked into Promises? You could do `someAjaxCall().then(redirectPageByExtractingHrefFromTheElem)` if `someAjaxCall` would return a Promise.

Comment: Every ajax call (starting jQuery 1.5) returns a promise. So, the then() method you suggested should work.

Comment: I don't want the page transition to wait for the Ajax callback, I just need to ensure that the call reaches server before page redirects. These are basically for analytics.

Comment: @appu In that case, your code should work as Ajax call would be fired right before the redirect happens. You may want to return false to teh onclick function to prevent default anchor(link) behavior.

Comment: @Piyush the first method works , but the second one is not working. As per my understanding the ajax will be fired then since it returns true the page will be redirected based on the href. But the ajax is not fired the page redirects before that. What is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: It depends on whether or not enough time has elapsed between the ajax request call being initiated and the call being aborted due to the redirect was enough time to hand off the complete request to the server. Another option would be to simply direct the user to the server, and have the server then redirect to the target page. No waiting on ajax, works with opening in new tab, and doesn't sometimes result in the ajax failing when the redirect happens too fast or the send takes too long.

Comment: @KevinB the server side implementation is good but I was trying to hit a third party service through the provided javascript library.
I think its better to put a setTimeout around the page navigation function so that both the ajax and page nav will be moved to the event queue and I will get a minimum wait period.

Comment: or, use xhr and look at the readystate to know when it has been sent, and then do the redirect, not waiting for response.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. I didn't knew about readystate 1 :)

Answer (score -1):

The default behavior of the hyperlink onclick and href properties is to execute the onclick, then follow the href as long as the onclick doesn't return false, the event hasn't been prevented.

Since you are returning `false` in your first code snippet you're able to make AJAX call.

```
<a onclick="return clickFn()" href="somelink"></a>
clickFn(){
  someAjaxCall()
   redirectPageByExtractingHrefFromTheElem()
   return false;
}
```

But in your second snippet you are returning `true` which will allows the browser to redirect to another page based on `href` attribute.
That is why you are unable to make AJAX call in your second service call.

```
<a onclick="return clickFn()" href="somelink"></a>
clickFn(){
   someAjaxCall()
   return true;
}
```

According to [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html)

> The default behavior associated with a link is the retrieval of another Web resource. This behavior is commonly and implicitly obtained by selecting the link (e.g., by clicking, through keyboard input, etc.).

So in order to prevent the default action you should use `preventDefault()` method of event to prevent the default action.

### Implementation.

pass `event` as a parameter to function clickFn and 
use [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default action.

```js
function clickFn(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  someAjaxCall();
  // var URL = event.target.href;
  redirectPageByExtractingHrefFromTheElem();
}
```

```html
<a onclick="clickFn(event)" href="somelink">somelink</a>
```

Comment: I know your code will work but why doesn't this one work:
`<a onclick="return clickFn()" href="somelink"></a>
    clickFn(){
      someAjaxCall()
      return true;
    }`

Comment: @appu because you are returning `true` which will allow browser to navigate to another URL. See the updated answer